# How to detect the phase sequence of a 3-phase ac (R-Y-B or R-B-Y) using Atmega32?

Tags: ac, avr, atmega, three-phase

I am using an 8-bit AVR microcontroller in my project to detect the phase sequence of a 3-phase AC supply. Which method shall I use to do the work with the least number of components required along with ATmega32?
I have thought of using zero crossing detectors but that would need a step-down transformer(for reducing 230V ac). Is there any other convenient way?
I have also found some other circuits and attached the images below[image] . [image])

But my purpose is to detect the sequence using only atmega32(no transformer should be used

Comment: What have you thought of so far? Have you got a hardware schematic? This sounds like homework so you need to show some effort or your question will be closed. Hit the edit link below your question.

Comment: What other techniques have you found when searching for zero-cross detection circuits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would use three opto-isolators, one per phase.  Use a "capacitive dropper" to feed the LED side of each opto-isolator - no transformer required.  Make sure you protect those LEDs from reverse voltage when the phase goes negative.

Comment: How to detect the sequence after that?

Comment: @RudrenduMahindar If each opto-isolator is fed by a half-wave rectifier, then each will switch on during the positive half-cycle, and off during the negative half-cycle.  So just look at the order in which the three phases turn on.

Comment: I understand that by looking at the order in which the three phases turn on, I can detect the phase sequence. How can I instruct the atmega32 to detect the sequence?

Comment: @RudrenduMahindar It's up to you to write the software for the atmega32.  If each opto-isolator is connected to an I/O pin (configured as an input), then write a program to detect the order in which the inputs switch on.  If it's 1 then 2 then 3 then 1 then 2 then 3... then the phase is rotating one way.  If it's 1 then 3 then 2 then 1 then 3 then 2... then the phase is the other way.

Comment: Ok, I shall think about a way to get the input sequence. Thank you @Simon B for your valuable guidance.